# Why does Firebase not recommend direct authentication with an access token when calling REST API?

Tags: python, r, firebase

The following is from [Firebase documentation on authenticating REST](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/auth#generate_an_access_token) requests. I'm wondering why the first approach (credentials object) is prefered? When they say you shouldn't "use the token directly", does this mean that it is problematic to hard code the actual text of the access token? Or does that mean you shouldn't use the access token as part of the URL endpoint?

I am an R user and I'm trying to pull .json files from Firebase. I'm using python to request the access token (because there does not appear to be an R package to do this), and then passing the access token into R to form part of the URL endpoint.

I have looked into the packages fireData (not maintained) and firebase (for Shiny), and I think accessing via the REST api is my best option.

In R:

```
library(reticulate)
library(httr)

reticulate::source_python("get_firebase_auth.py")
```

get_firebase_auth.py:

```
from google.oauth2 import service_account
from google.auth.transport.requests import AuthorizedSession

# Define the required scopes
scopes = [
  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email",
  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase.database"
]

# Authenticate a credential with the service account
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
    "path/to/serviceAccountKey.json", scopes=scopes)

# Use the credentials object to authenticate a Requests session.
authed_session = AuthorizedSession(credentials)
response = authed_session.get(
    "https://<DATABASE_NAME>.firebaseio.com/users/ada/name.json")

# Or, use the token directly, as described in the "Authenticate with an
# access token" section below. **(not recommended)**
request = google.auth.transport.requests.Request()
credentials.refresh(request)
access_token = credentials.token
```

Then in R:

```
GET(paste0("https:<DATABASE_NAME>/.json&access_token=", access_token)
```

It's working fine and I'm getting the data I need, I'm just new to APIs and Firebase and want to understand if there is a security risk with including the access token variable in the URL endpoint.

More info in case it's helpful to others:

Based on the comments from r2evans below, I was able to do some more digging in the documentation and found this:

*After an application obtains an access token, it sends the token to a Google API in an HTTP Authorization request header. It is possible to send tokens as URI query-string parameters, but we don't recommend it, because URI parameters can end up in log files that are not completely secure. Also, it is good REST practice to avoid creating unnecessary URI parameter names.*

So for a more secure process, I need to add a request header in R:

```
GET(paste0("https:<DATABASE_NAME>/.json,
add_headers(`Authorization` = access_token))
```

Comment: Are you asking why they are recommending against hard-coding a password (aka API key) into your source code? My guess is it's insecure to do so. (This doesn't mean I think it's easy to get an OAuth token in R. It's not, and since I don't need it, I don't know off-hand how to do it.) If your question is "why do they recommend", it's likely that I just answered your question. You can now choose to either hard-code your API key, or you can rewrite your question (or write a new one) to *"how to do firebase/oauth in R?"*

Comment: ... and for that, a brief search suggests that https://github.com/Kohze/fireData/blob/0cfd8a2b06e37f286538e3364d1602b52dd22454/R/index.R#L322 might be a useful reference for you?

Comment: Is the security issue that you shouldn't paste the actual access token text into the script? Or, is it that it shouldn't be sent directly as part of the URL endpoint? In this example, I'm not hard-coding anything. I'm using the reticulate package to pass the python variable "access_token" into R, to be used as part of the URL. I've updated the question to hopefully make that clearer.

Comment: That's a fair question. Hard-coding is clearly a problem, good that you're not doing that (I assume it's being stored and retrieved in a secure-ish fashion). Yes, though, API keys are potentially full-access passwords, so some sites prefer re-authorizing via the OAuth process in lieu of storing an API key. And yet other sites allow API keys with no expiration or limited functionality, so there's a full spectrum of "good-to-not-as-good".

Comment: Thank-you! That really helped clarify what I needed